# npm install cube Error: No dist in websocket-server package

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, npm, cube

Ubuntu 14.04 with newly installed `nodejs` `npm` `mongodb`
Install cube by `npm install cube` and it throws the errors：

```
npm ERR! Error: No dist in websocket-server package
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:746:26)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:739:5
npm ERR!     at RegClient.get_ (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:105:14)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:41:12)
npm ERR!     at fs.js:268:14
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:103:5
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/me/cube
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/cube/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've tried `sudo npm install cube`, but it doesn't work too.
I've search the error info by google and sf, I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error:

the official source is not available:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket-server

It's seems [the developer's website](https://tonicdev.com/npm/websocket-server) is closed...

I found the solution by browse the [ResqueBoard Issues](https://github.com/wa0x6e/ResqueBoard/issues/39)

Try this:

```
cd node_modules/
git clone https://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server
mv node-websocket-server websocket-server
cd..
npm install cube
```

use the `node-websocket-server` to replace `websocket-server`.